# Create a uniqueness index on multiple columns depending on the value to be added postgres 9.6

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, unique-index

I am not sure if my query is executable after reading all the postgres documentation, but I want to ask if it is possible to write a uniqueness index, so that it considers unique not only those values that are EQUAL to existing ones, but for example if the date of a new record being added is less than or equal to existing records with an identical id ?

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_unique_index
    ON my_table (id, currentDate)
    WHERE currentDate < NEW.currentDate
```

So INSERT would behave like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, currentDate) VALUES 
(0, '12.21.2022'), - succefull added
(0, '12.24.2022'), - succefull added
(0, '12.23.2022'), - unique error
(1, '12.24.2022') - succefull added
```

I'm actually trying to do a much more complex uniqueness condition across multiple tables and with more conditions, but because of the problems even at the beginning of creating an index, I would like to know this first

Comment: Could you provide some examples of unique and non-unique records? Just to be sure it's clear. Edit them into your question.

Comment: The uniqueness conditions that I have given as an example could confuse you with their meaninglessness, but you should not pay much attention to them
My main question is - how to create a uniqueness index so that in its condition it is possible to use the values from the added row in comparison with the rest of the already added rows

Comment: While you can make indexes on expressions, I don't think you can refer to other rows or make queries. I think you might have to do this with an insert or update trigger.

Comment: Version 9.6 is rather outdated and is unsupported, you could still use a daterange type and create an overlap constraint to avoid ranges in the past. Check the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/rangetypes.html

Comment: You also seem think SQL data is ordered whereas it is not. So this `currentDate < NEW.currentDate`  means nothing.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Uniqueness is a criterion applied to a set of rows regardless of their order or insertion time, it does not distinguish a "new row" and compare it to "existing ones".

To achieve that, you would need to use a [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) that can check the inserted/updated row against the maximum date.

An alternative would be to use an [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION) on a range of dates, and make each row that you insert cover the range since the last insert, preventing further rows to be inserted with a date before that.

Answer (score 0):

While you can make indexes on expressions, I don't think you can refer to other rows or make queries. Same with check constraints. You need a trigger, as the [Postgresql check docs say](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS)...

> If what you desire is a one-time check against other rows at row insertion, rather than a continuously-maintained consistency guarantee, a custom trigger can be used to implement that. (This approach avoids the dump/restore problem because pg_dump does not reinstall triggers until after restoring data, so that the check will not be enforced during a dump/restore.)

Comment: I already use a trigger to check the uniqueness, but it creates problems for multi-threaded row recording because when two transactions write two identical rows simultaneously, the trigger performs a uniqueness check for transactions and since the trigger works BEFORE applying the transaction, there are no conflicting records in the database at the time of checking, the check is successful and then the database is simultaneously written two identical records :(

Comment: @AgroShkolnik Does [this article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/triggers-to-enforce-constraints/) help?

Comment: @AgroShkolnik So what do you want to happen in that circumstance?

Comment: this article looks like something that will help me, thank you